# Recursion prevents function from being clicked more times in a row

Tags: javascript, css, recursion

I have created a simple script using recursion, to change the position of images.

It loop throught them and adjust their position , the script is relative easy code :

```
var img = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
 var X = 0;
 var Y = 0;
 var check;

 function all() {
   var decko = img.children;
   for (var i = 0; i < decko.length; i++) {
     if (i !== 0 && i % 3 === 0) {
       X = 0;
       Y++;
     }
     decko[i].style.transform = "translate3d(" + X * 100 + "px," + Y * 100 + "px,0)";
     X++;
   }
   X = 0;
   Y = 0;
   check = false;
 }
 all()

 window.onclick = function() {


   pushIt(img.length, img.children, 0, 0)

 }

 function pushIt(max, target, index, count) {

   if (count == max) {
     return;
   }
   var tmp = target[index];
   var matrix =window.getComputedStyle(tmp).getPropertyValue("transform");
     var translate_left=matrix.split(",")[4];
     var translate_top=matrix.split(",")[5].split(")")[0]-100;
   tmp.style.transform = "translate3d(" + translate_left + "px," + translate_top + "px,0)";
     setTimeout(function(){
        pushIt(max, target, index + 1, count + 1);
     },150)


 }
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Trolstover/chaLdjxz/)  you can see how it works. The problem is when there are a lot of images.

When i click which invokes the function , it loops throught all images ( 30 + in my case ). If i click two times in a sec , it will loop throught the all images , and THEN it will execute the function 2 nd time which is in my case unwanted behavior ( looks laggy ). Is there any way to prevent this behavior? I have chosen recursion , bcs it seems like easiest choice for this.

Answer (score 1):

You had a couple if issues with your JavaScript that were throwing some errors, namely max was undefined in your function. I got this working [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/9jtsvzxs/)

```
var img = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
var decko = img.children;
var X = 0;
var Y = 0;
var check;
var running = false;

function all() {
    for (var i = 0; i < decko.length; i++) {
        if (i !== 0 && i % 3 === 0) {
            X = 0;
            Y++;
        }
        decko[i].style.transform = "translate3d(" + X * 100 + "px," + Y * 100 + "px,0)";
        X++;
    }
    X = 0;
    Y = 0;
    check = false;
}
all()

window.onclick = function () {

    if (!running) {
        running = true;
        pushIt(decko.length, img.children, 0, 0);
    }
}

var pushIt = function (max, target, index, count) {

    if (count == max) {
        running = false;
        return;
    }
    var tmp = target[index];
    var matrix = window.getComputedStyle(tmp).getPropertyValue("transform");
    var translate_left = matrix.split(",")[4];
    var translate_top = matrix.split(",")[5].split(")")[0] - 100;
    tmp.style.transform = "translate3d(" + translate_left + "px," + translate_top + "px,0)";
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(running);
        pushIt(max, target, index + 1, count + 1);
    }, 150)
}
```